# {_placeholder:true,num:0} Socket io

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, binary

Im sending binary data to client and socket io adding extra message like: `{_placeholder:true,num:0}`, to solve this i added parser schemapack which needs to solve this problem. So this is my code in server

```
const resultObj = {
                body: message,
                user: user.name,
                own: user.id,
                // time: message.createdAt.toString,
            }
            const resultObjSchema = build({
                body: 'string',
                user: 'string',
                own: 'uint8',
                // time: 'string'
              });
              let buffer = resultObjSchema.encode(resultObj);
```

So im still getting this additional data which i want to remove. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeOrZ.png)

I tried what i already said but still not working